# What is the meaning of points $\tau$ in the upper half-plane which are not CM-points but with $j(\tau)$ an algebraic integer?

Tags: modular-forms, modular-function

Due to the relation between imaginary quadratic fields and complex multiplication ($CM$) one knows that for all $CM$-points in the upper half-plane

$$\mathbb{H}:=\{z \in \mathbb{C}:\ Im\ z>0\}$$

the value $j(\tau)$ of the modular $j$-function is an algebraic integer.

Is there an arithmetic significance also of the other points $\tau \in \mathbb{H}$ with $j(\tau)$ an algebraic integer?

Comment: When $\tau$ is CM then $\sigma(j(\tau))= j(\rho)$ where $\Bbb{Z+\rho Z}$ is an invertible fractional $\Bbb{Z}[\tau]$-ideal with non-trivial ideal class. Do you think something related happens when $\tau$ is non CM ?

Comment: $\sigma$ denotes an element of the Galois group of the number field? - My question leaves the given imaginary quadratic field. Instead, it asks for possible other arithmetic objects related to algebraic integer values of $j$ which do not originate from CM-points. Possibly objects which are not related to imaginary quadratic fields.